# Finite quotients groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm not sure about this question.

Is the group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, a finite group?

I Think this answer is yes, but why?

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you think the answer is yes?

Comment: I'm working with the subring $A$ of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ generated by $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, $1/(1-2i)$ and $1/(2-3i)$. And I know that $A/nA$ is finite, but is the same with $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1) For $\;0\le k\ne m\le n\;,\;\;k+n\Bbb Z\neq m+n\Bbb Z$

2) For all $\;h\in\Bbb Z\;$ there exists $\;j\in n\Bbb Z\;,\;\;0\le j\le n\;$ s.t. $\;h+n\Bbb Z=j+n\Bbb Z$

Deduce that $\;\left|\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z\right|=n\;$